# Use multiple guard on one route in laravel

Tags: laravel

How i can use multiple guard on one route in laravel?
I have two guard: admin-api, user-api and i want to check if token for user is valid can be accessible, and if token not valid in users table, check token in admins table.

I use the following code but just second middleware Applied.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')
        ->middleware('auth:api-admin')
        ->post('/user' , 'UserController@user');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an array of middlewares to your routes

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'auth:api-admin'])->post('/user', 'UserController@user');
```

Comment: Then I suppose one of the checks is stopping the request.

Comment: In that case I think you are better of writing a third middleware that checks both and continues if one passes.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while this question asked, but the other way to check multiple guards within one route without adding a custom middleware is pass several guards to `auth` middleware:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api,api-admin'])->post('/user', 'UserController@user');
```